# print value older than date shell

Tags: shell, date, compare

I  have file with this:

```
 1. something1 2015/04/15   
 2. something2 2015/02/06   
 3. something3 2015/05/09 
 4. something4 2015/05/15 
 5. something5 2015/09/20
```

And I want print everything older than `date=2015/05/09`

```
`awk ' $2 < $date ' file`
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to pass shell variables to awk with the `-v` option:

```
date="2015/05/09"
awk -v d="$date" '$NF < d' file
```

prints the first 2 lines